# At what point does an std::map make more sense for grouping objects compared to two vectors and a linear search?

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, stl

I am trying to sort a large collection of objects into a series of groups, which represent some kind of commonality between them.

There seems to be two ways I can go about this:

1) I can manage everything by hand, sorting out all the objects into a vector of vectors. However, this means that I have to iterate over all the upper level vectors every time I want to try and find an existing group for an ungrouped object. I imagine this will become very computationally expensive very quickly as the number of disjoint groups increases.

2) I can use the identifiers of each object that I'm using to classify them as a key for an std::map, where the value is a vector. At that point, all I have to do is iterate over all the input objects once, calling myMap[object.identifier].push_back(object) each time. The map will sort everything out into the appropriate vector, and then I can just iterate over the resulting values afterwards.

My question is...

Which method would be best to use? It seems like a vector of vectors would be faster initially, but it's going to slow down as more and more groups are created. AFAIK, std::map uses RB trees internally, which means that finding the appropriate vector to add the object to should be faster, but you're going to pay for that when the tree inevitably needs to be rebalanced.

The additional memory consumption from an std::map doesn't matter. I'm dealing with anywhere from 12000 to 80000 individual objects that need to be grouped together, and I expect there to be anywhere from 12000 to 20000 groups once everything is said and done.

Comment: They are not equivalent. For the vector solution, you'd also need to take care of removing duplicates. But, time it. And have a look at [boost flat map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx).

Comment: Performance-wise a flat *-esque structure is fastest until about 30-40 items, when the unordered_* take over. At no point is a RB-tree the fastest solution (average case). It's my favorite way of making software run faster - replace all maps by unordered_maps if they don't use order.

Comment: Do you actually *have* performance issues? Or is this just a general consideration? In the latter case I'd vote for implementing the most readable solution, the one that best reflects whatever you try to model / simulate.

Comment: Considering the access interface, I'd (personally) prefer map<vector> over vector<vector>. But especially if your categories are known beforehand, you could use an enum for them and use it to access-by-index a pre-allocated vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using either of your mentioned approaches directly, I suggest you evaluate the use of `std::unordered_map` (docs [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)) for your use case. It uses maps with buckets and hashed values internally and has average constant complexity for search, insertion and removal.